# Case where solution does not obey maximum principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Find a solution of the equation $$ -\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} - u = -1$$ in the interval $|x| < 1$ which does not obey the maximum principle.

The maximum principle: If $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ satisfies $\Delta u \geq 0$ in $\Omega$, then either $u$ is a constant , or $u(\xi) < \sup \limits_{x \in \Omega} u (x)$ for all $\xi \in \Omega$

So, I have computed the general solution of the above equation and got the general solution as $u(x) = c_1 cos(x) + c_2sin(x) +1$ but I am struggling to find such solution that does not obey the maximum principle.

Obviously, $u(x)$ is not a constant but how should I find such solution such  that the second condition  $u(\xi) < \sup \limits_{x \in \Omega} u (x)$ for all $\xi \in \Omega$ does not hold.

Comment: Is $\Omega$ allowed to be a closed set?

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding the question, I think the $\Omega$ in this case is $|x| <1$ ? So, the $\Omega$ should be open

Comment: $c_1\cos \left(x\right)+c_2\sin \left(x\right)+1$

Comment: @Silver Would you mind to explain a little bit more?